# I want to select all the photos present in various canvas tag using Selenium module in Python

Tags: python, selenium, canvas

> **Note**: You can see the HTML tree [HERE](https://www.icloud.com/#photos). 
>   **Important:** First you need to have an ***icloud ID*** to login into ***icloud.com*** and secondly you need to be an ***apple device*** user and ***icloud photo sharing*** should be enabled on your device so that you can see your photo library on the given link.

Canvas having particular height and width should be clicked. I am quite new to selenium and I am not even sure if this is possible or not.

I am getting on the *mentioned link* through the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys

browser.get('http://www.icloud.com')
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("auth-frame"))
account_name = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "appleId")))
account_name.send_keys('abc@icloud.com')
action = action_chains.ActionChains(browser)
action.send_keys(keys.Keys.TAB)
action.send_keys('my_password')
action.send_keys(keys.Keys.ENTER)
action.perform()
browser.get('https://www.icloud.com/#photos')
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("photos"))
```

Further, I want to click on all the **canvas tags** available on the page(If it's possible) which have ***height and width of 139***

Below is one of the **canvas tag**:

```
<div class="p2-base-flow-grid-item-view" draggable="true" style="transform: 
translateZ(0px) translateX(105.6px) translateY(101.76px); z-index: 1264;">
    <canvas width="139" height="139" style="width: 89px; height: 89px;">
    </canvas>
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not locate an element in canvas,  I am tried it on several script but i don't able to locate element on canvas

Comment: I thought so. is there no other way to select these pictures?
Thankyou @iamsankalp89

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is there, I spend more than 6 days on this. but i don't get the answer. So Solution which I write is the only right now :):)

Comment: Let's see if someone else will provide an answer or not.
Well, your question doesn't help me in any way, it just tells me something I have already mentioned in my question. @iamsankalp89

Comment: Yes. @iamsankalp89